# How to have nested Orderables?

Tags: django, wagtail

We have a content model with a couple of many-to-many (type) relationships:

```
Issue has many Articles
Article has many Authors
```

In this specific case, our Article and Author models are fairly small. The use case is to construct a table of contents for a magazine Issue by creating a list of Article titles and one or more Authors for each Article. Ideally, the end-user could edit the entire Issue from a single form, since the articles are only used as a table of contents.

I have tried to model this using the Page and Orderable classes, as follows. However, I am getting a `KeyError` when wagtail attempts to render the Issue edit form.

```py
class Author(Orderable):
    """
    Represents authorship for an article
    allowing multiple authors per article
    and multiple articles per author
    """
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        "magazine.Article",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="authors",
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailcore.Page",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="articles_authored",
    )

    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel(
            "author", ["contact.Person", "contact.Organization"]
        )
    ]


class Article(Orderable):
    """
    An article, which can have multiple authors
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    issue = ParentalKey(
        "magazine.ArchiveIssue",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="articles",
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("title", classname="full"),
        # Multiple authors can contribute to an article
        InlinePanel(
            "authors",
            heading="Authors",
            help_text="Select one or more authors, who contributed to this article",
        ),
    ]


class Issue(Page):
    """
    Represents a magazine issue
    with table of contents
    """
    # Add articles inline, since it is a table of contents
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel(
            "articles",
            heading="Table of contents",
            help_text="Select one or more authors, who contributed to this article",
        ),
    ]
```

Django throws a `KeyError` exception when trying to render the Wagtail edit page:

```
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    'authors'
```

I realize I may be asking too much of Wagtail here, but this seems like it might be possible. At the very least, I hope to get a better understanding of why this isn't working and might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the nested orderables aspect, but if planning to order `Authors` on `Article` then `Author.article` should be a `ParentalKey`, and `Article` would also need to extend `ClusterableModel`.